# deep linking - handle onBackPressed in situation where was already launched

Tags: android, deep-linking

i want to implement deep-linking as requested here:
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test

"The back button returns to the previous screen.
After opening a deep link, pressing 'Back' from the deep linked content should lead users directly back to the search results page. Test this by creating an HTML page with deep links (described below). After following one of the deep links from the browser to the app content, the 'Back' button should take the user back to the page containing the deep link. It should not lead to other content within the app or prompt for confirmation."

my problem is when my app is launched - > **first** activity is Started-> pressing home button -> using deeplinking (**and now i am starting a different activity**) -> back button is not getting me back to search results page. instead, onResume() called on the first activity. System.exit(0) not helping as it makes the app relaunch again (when onBackpressed is called).

thanks

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the Android Platform.

Comment: Refer to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326437/back-navigation-after-deep-link-by-navigation-architecture-component)

Answer (score -1):

It's depend on what you want to do.
1. Start a new application for deeplink
2. Start new application if app is already not running and if running us that app and go to appropriate activity.

in 1st case it's possible to come back to page from where deeplink was launched but I am not sure about 2nd case when app is already running.